# Adding supllimentary group so that user can have access

Tags: permissions, opensuse

I am using opensuse. I have created a directory projects under /srv and set its permissions to  770 and `chown -R wwwrun:developer /srv/projects/`
I have used
`usermod -a -G developer username`
but I can't access that directory, I always get permission denied entry.
I want to clone a git repo in projects so that only apache and group of developer able to rwx it.

Comment: You need to login again for that change to take effect

Comment: Unless you want to serve the git repository through the web server, don't let apache access it (the `.git` repository storage) - too dangerous.

Comment: Thanks. I usually do `chown -R git:developer` .git`  and `chmod 770 -R .git`.  is that right?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: Logging again worked. I also read that opening another terminal window will also do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

(in addition to what you have done)

```
#chgrp -R developer /srv/projects/
```

Comment: Because it is already under the same group, how above statement going to make difference? opening new term or logging again worked.